# Node Js : Asynchronous while loop with variables updates

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, while-loop, callback

I am facing a case I did not manage to handle within my Node Js code.

Here is the point :

I need to call this function

```
addClosestTask = function(currentTask,taskArray,travel_mode,time_p,callback_p){
    async.mapLimit(taskArray,3,function(task,callback_async){
        map.getTravelTime(currentTask["destination"]["location"][1],currentTask["destination"]["location"][0],task["destination"]["location"][1],task["destination"]["location"][0],travel_mode,true,callback_async);
    },function(error,result){
        if(error){
            callback(true,null,null);
        }
        else{
            var min_time = _.min(result);
            var min_index = _.findIndex(result,function(item){
                return item == min_time ;
            });
            if(time_p + 240 + min_time < 2400){
                callback_p(null,taskArray[min_index],time_p + 240 + min_time);
            }
            else{
                callback_p(true,null,null);
            }
        }
    });
};
```

There is a starting currentTask and taskArray. travel_mode is always constant.

I need to call this function until an error is passed to the callback first argument. 
After each call I need to update currentTask with the task returned by the callback second argument and time_p with the time return by the callback third argument. I also need to update taskArray by a simple operation that depends on the task returned. When everything is updated I make the next call up to the point en error is called (which will eventually be the case because of the condition on the time. I also have an array in which I need to add the returned task everytime.

I obviously tried to look at async module functions but did not find one that could handle my issue.

Do you know how I could solve that ?

Thank you very much, I can't find a way to get out of this issue.